# How to execute decrypted file automatically without specifying it's path?

Tags: c#, windows, encryption

Need help T_T
I'm running the code below to Decrypt an exe File I'm trying to Run it and Automatically execute the Decrypted file would it be possible to execute it without saving it's data to the disk?

I'm also trying to run it without the need of specifying the encrypted file name but have no idea what changes need to be done for this to happen or if it's even possible.

> FileInfo encFile = new FileInfo("7GNTBBASDADASDASDASDASDASDASDASDSW7VBKGUX5TB5XBXDG3W4DWC6K6JBMTG7C2OYEHNPSN4PE6JYLJDUA"); // < File name in the current directory

```
const int ReadBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            // DECRYPTION     

            FileInfo encFile = new FileInfo("7GNTBBASDADASDASDASDASDASDASDASDSW7VBKGUX5TB5XBXDG3W4DWC6K6JBMTG7C2OYEHNPSN4PE6JYLJDUA"); // < File name in the current directory 

            byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String("SWW/HAWEWQF/F2d/WrSSA==");

            byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("ASDSADSAwwqIM221vASXG1221nqk=");
            // DECRYPTION     
     
            // DECRYPTION     

            using (FileStream inp = encFile.OpenRead())
            using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                aes.KeySize = 256;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                aes.IV = iv;
                aes.Key = key;

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(inp, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // crypted file structure: {name length x4}{full file name}{data length x8}{data}{sha512 hash of data x64}

                    byte[] nameLengthBits = new byte[2];
                    if (cs.Read(nameLengthBits, 0, 2) != 2)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed reading file name size");
                        return;
                    }
                    ushort nameLength = BitConverter.ToUInt16(nameLengthBits, 0);

                    byte[] originalName = new byte[nameLength];
                    if (cs.Read(originalName, 0, nameLength) != nameLength)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed reading file name");
                        return;
                    }
                    string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalName);

                    byte[] dataLengthBits = new byte[8];
                    if (cs.Read(dataLengthBits, 0, dataLengthBits.Length) != dataLengthBits.Length)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed reading data length");
                        return;
                    }
                    long dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(dataLengthBits, 0);

                    string outputFileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                    if (File.Exists(outputFileName))
              
                    {
                       
                    }

                    byte[] decryptedHash;
                    long totalRead = 0;
                    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
                    using (SHA512Managed hasher = new SHA512Managed())



                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[ReadBufferSize];
                        long bytesRemaining = dataLength;
                        while (bytesRemaining > 0)
                        {
                            int readingThisRound = ReadBufferSize < bytesRemaining ? ReadBufferSize : (int)bytesRemaining;
                            int bytesRead = cs.Read(buffer, 0, readingThisRound);
                            totalRead += bytesRead;

                            // dump decrypted data to file
                            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }

                        //
                 


                            //

                            hasher.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);
                        decryptedHash = hasher.Hash;}




                    byte[] originalHashBits = new byte[64];
                    if (cs.Read(originalHashBits, 0, originalHashBits.Length) != originalHashBits.Length)  using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        
                    }
                     
                    if (originalHashBits.SequenceEqual(decryptedHash))
```